# StackExchange.Redis how to query all db Keys

Tags: stackexchange.redis

I'm trying to find some Keys that follow a pattern, but I need all related keys not just the ones in a specific server.

Until now I'm trying to access a specific server using documentation example, but it doesn't work.

```
        var connection = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(new ConfigurationOptions
        {
            EndPoints = { { DemoSettings.CustomerRedisCache.Url, DemoSettings.CustomerRedisCache.Port } },
            Password = DemoSettings.CustomerRedisCache.Password
        });

        var server = connection.GetServer(host: DemoSettings.CustomerRedisCache.Url, 
                                          port: DemoSettings.CustomerRedisCache.Port);
        var cadena = "cust:" + data.SearchString.Replace(' ', ':')+"*";
        var valores = server.Keys(pattern: cadena);
```

Last line always fail because of a timeout :S

I'll appreciate any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, what redis server version are you using? The server commands available varies between servers, and on versions before 2.8 the `KEYS` command must be used instead of the `SCAN` command. The `KEYS` command is well known for causing major performance problems and should never be used in production, except perhaps on a slave. If you are using < 2.8, yes I would expect `KEYS` to cause timeouts.

However, ultimately both `SCAN` and `KEYS` suggest that you aren't using redis in the intended way. You should not ever find yourself needing to use those commands for regular operations. The only tools that *should* use them routinely are admin / data exploration tools. And *they* should ideally target slaves, not masters.

There are usually alternative ways to do anything that people tend to want `SCAN` and `KEYS` for - for example, by storing the keys in a particular group in a single set (`SADD` etc)

Comment: I'm using redis cache on Azure. Actually I'm just trying to run a demo and make work as expected. I suppose the best way to achieve that task is to  store the actual keys in another dictionary acting like an index?

Comment: @JuanK that does make we wonder whether Azure is letting us know the server version; I would expect Azure to expose `SCAN`, not just `KEYS` - and `SCAN` should not timeout

Comment: How can I ask for SCAN instead of KEYS with StackOverflow.Redis ? Sorry if It's a dumb question but I'm just implementing my first Redis application.

Comment: @Juank normally the library takes care of this for you automatically. You could try setting the server version (in the connection data) to something >= 2.8 - see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

if you need all KEY*, keeping them in a value will increase the speed. You can keep the object under AllKeys to display all Keys.

SetAllObject

```
server.StringSetAsync("AllKeys", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj));
```

GetAllObject

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TEntity>>(await server.StringGetAsync("AllKeys")).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public record struct SearchResult (string Input, string Output, bool IsAckNack);

public IEnumerable<SearchResult> Search(string id)
{
    var connection = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(new ConfigurationOptions
    {
        EndPoints = { { DemoSettings.CustomerRedisCache.Url, DemoSettings.CustomerRedisCache.Port } },
        Password = DemoSettings.CustomerRedisCache.Password
    });
    var cadena = "cust:" + id.Replace(' ', ':')+"*";

    var server = connection.GetServer(host: DemoSettings.CustomerRedisCache.Url, port: DemoSettings.CustomerRedisCache.Port);
    var keys = server.Keys(pattern: cadena);
    var db = connection.GetDatabase();
    var results = new List<SearchResult>();
    Console.WriteLine($"Found {keys.Count()} keys matching {id}");
    var counter = 0;
    foreach (var key in keys)
    {
        var item = db.HashGetAll(key);
        var result = new SearchResult();
        foreach (var field in item)
        {
            result = (string)field.Name switch
            {
                "input" => result with { Input = field.Value },
                "output" => result with { Output = field.Value },
                "ack" or "nack" => result with { IsAckNack = true, Output = field.Value.ToString().FormatJson()},
                _ => result
            };
        }
        counter++;
        if(counter > 250){
            yield break;
        }
        yield return result;
    }
}
```